# Usage of present/past tense with "would"

Tags: grammar, tense, grammaticality, will-would

I am not able to decide that out of below 2 sentences which one is grammatically correct. Please note that I want to know from international competitive exams perspective. All good/additional information you may provide with the answer would be highly and sincerely appreciated.

> - If he would bet on horse races in spite of your warning, he ***deserved***
>     to lose his money.
> - If he would bet on horse races in spite of your warning *then* he
>     ***deserves*** to lose his money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct; however both are from a particular and somewhat *refined* English dialect (the kind you'd expect to read in a 19th century novel) so finding good illustrative examples is going to be difficult.

In this case "would" reflects its relationship with "will", as in *intention* or *determination*.  The first sentence talks about something that has already happened and its consequence:

> If he **was so determined** to bet on the races **that he did so** in spite of your objection, (then) **it's his own fault** that he **lost** his money.

The second sentence is a typical conditional that talks about some future hypothetical action:

> If he **is** so determined to bet on the races that he **will do** so in spite of your objection, (then) **it will be his own fault** when he **loses** his money.

In either case, the "then" is optional.

I can't tell you which would definitely be correct on an "international exam", as many of these rely on so-called "rules" which are not always followed by actual English speakers and their many, many dialects.  After all, something like:

> It ain't no thing

would be marked *incorrect* on an exam, even though it's a fairly common expression.

If forced to pick between the two, the second sentence is a more standard example of a hypothetical and is probably correct.  Probably.

Comment: Will you please explain "refined English dialect"? Where is this dialect used? How broad / narrow is it?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Good one, with nice explanation. +1.